# Why does Vergara attempt to convince the others that there is nothing supernatural afoot?

Tags: thirty-coins

In at least the first few episodes of *30 Coins* (*30 Monedas*), the priest Father Vergara attempts to, essentially, gaslight various people, particularly Elena, into believing that any apparent supernatural events are mere stress-induced hallucinations.

This was not only singularly ineffective—Paco and particularly Elena continued to believe that there was something supernatural afoot—but seemed guaranteed to never have had a chance. Not only was Elena attacked by an enormous monster with the injuries to prove it, but Paco also saw the same creature rip the door off an ambulance, Elena and several police officers saw an out-of-shape middle-aged woman knock an officer about ten feet with a backhand, and the church was trashed for weeks afterwards, with pews weighing hundreds of pounds scattered around like ninepins (by the same person after having been *shot five times and seemingly having been dead*). And that's just the start!

Even worse, it made Elena less likely to cooperate with him, since besides the fact that no one likes to be called crazy, as she pointed out, if the coin was just as useless piece of metal then he had no reason to need it back.

Why did Vergara pursue this strategy in light of its evident ineffectiveness and indeed counterproductivity?

Comment: Not to make the question too long, but he also tries to convince people that a human(ish) baby born from a cow was somehow switched while no one was looking, despite the evident fact that a half-dozen people were there, would have noticed a racket from someone *putting a newborn baby into a cow's uterus*, and they literally saw the attached umbilical cord. Then *he* tells Elena that the baby turned into a monster and escaped, and then he tries to deny it *again*  later. Oh, and these people already have reason to mistrust him because they know him to be a convicted murderer.